# PHP table filling

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble in displaying the data in table.
code take multiple id's , run them against database and display the result in table.

```
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($_POST['multi'] as  $artid) {
          $quee = 'select w.title, m.mediatype,w.year,w.len,w.heigh,w.size  from works w left join  `media` m on w.media_id = m.media_id  where w.work_id = "' . $artid.'"';
          $rs=$DBH->query($quee); 
          $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
            { 
                 $str1 = $row['title'] ."</br>".$row['mediatype']."</br>".$row['len'] ."x".$row['heigh'] . " ".$row['size']."</br>".$row['year'];

        echo '<tr>';
        if($counter == 0) {
        echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
        $counter = 1;
        break;
        }
        echo '<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>';
        if($counter == 1) {
        echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
        $counter = 0;
        break;
        }
        echo '</tr>';   

}

        }
```

**Output i am getting**
[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

any guesses what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($_POST['multi'] as  $artid) {
$quee = 'select w.title, m.mediatype,w.year,w.len,w.heigh,w.size  from works w left join  `media` m on w.media_id = m.media_id  where w.work_id = "' . $artid.'"';
$rs=$DBH->query($quee); 
$rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;

while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{ 
   $str1 = $row['title'] ."</br>".$row['mediatype']."</br>".$row['len'] ."x".$row['heigh'] . " ".$row['size']."</br>".$row['year'];

    if($counter == 0) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
    $counter = 1;
    break;
    }
    echo '<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>';
    if($counter == 1) {
    echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
    $counter = 0;
    echo '</tr>';  
    break;
    }
}

}
```

Keep echo  under if($counter == 0 ) so that it will create new row when counter is 0 and keep  under if($counter == 1)

how it will resovle problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the counter to add the width mark-up only to the first row. This isn't necessary. This is enough to achieve what you want:

```
echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$str1.'</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'.$str1.'</td>
      </tr>';
```

And add some css, like so:

```
tr:first-child td {
    width:10%;
}

tr:first-child td:first-child, tr:first-child td:last-child {
     width:45%;
}
```

to set the proper widths for the first row.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're breaking out of your while early for both values of $counter. So the html output is likely to be invalid rather than what you're expecting.

When $counter is 0 you break out before outputting the padding cell or the closing .
You can remove the breaks and use else, to make sure you always reach the closing . But you will still only output one populated cell per row because you output a full .. for each loop.

To get two records per row you need to close the row only after outputing the second record - perhaps like this:

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $str1 = $row['title'] ."</br>".$row['mediatype']."</br>".$row['len'] ."x".$row['heigh'] . " ".$row['size']."</br>".$row['year'];

        if($counter == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
            $counter = 1;
        } else {
            echo '<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>';
            echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
            $counter = 0;
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    }
```

EDIT: Also you should check if the whole thing ended on a 1 count, and close the row in that case too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the result you posted (and what you expected), maybe you could try to move line `echo '</tr>'` inside the second `if`?

I.e. Change this:

```
if($counter == 1) {
    echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
    $counter = 0;
    break;
}
echo '</tr>';
```

to this:

```
if($counter == 1) {
    echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';   
    $counter = 0;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your utilisation of the "break" statement : break will stop the execution of the closest while or for statement (in your example it is the while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) execution that will be broke).

What is happening here is the following :

first while loop print "tr" then do

```
echo ''. $str1 .'';
```

as you have $counter == 0, , you set $counter = 1 then the break is executed.

second loop, you are printing another "tr" without closing the first one (so this lead to a strange behaviour), now $counter ==1 is true and you will print the two "td"

Remmoving the break, and everything should work fine

```
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($_POST['multi'] as  $artid) {
          $quee = 'select w.title, m.mediatype,w.year,w.len,w.heigh,w.size  from works w left join  `media` m on w.media_id = m.media_id  where w.work_id = "' . $artid.'"';
          $rs=$DBH->query($quee); 
          $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
            { 
                 $str1 = $row['title'] ."</br>".$row['mediatype']."</br>".$row['len'] ."x".$row['heigh'] . " ".$row['size']."</br>".$row['year'];

        echo '<tr>';
        if($counter == 0) {
        echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
        $counter = 1;
        }
        echo '<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>';
        if($counter == 1) {
        echo '<td width="45%">'. $str1 .'</td>';
        $counter = 0;
        }
        echo '</tr>';   

}

        }
```

Comment: tried code without using break , getting duplicates http://i.imgur.com/TeAHXTj.png

Comment: Have you considered you might be getting duplicates because you're printing the same string twice? Look at your code: you're printing $str1 in both columns.

Comment: You're right didn't see exactly what you were trying to do